# Break in Smarty's / Dwoo's foreach

Tags: php, smarty, dwoo

About `break`

```
foreach ( $data as $k => $v ) {
  if ( $k == 4 ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

every one knows.

Is there something similar in `Smarty`'s or `Dwoo`'s `{foreach}` function ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should put your logic in php, not in template. However, you can write your own compiler plugin:

```
function smarty_compiler_break($contents, &$smarty){
   return 'break;';
}
```

and save it to `compiler.break.php` in your plugins directory.

Now in template you can use `{break}`.

Answer (score 2):

@Antonio: typical PHP developer retort, indeed :) Using Smarty largely depends on app requirements and developer/designer preferences. Here are some typical use case examples, and how Smarty plays a role:

http://www.smarty.net/use_cases

If you don't like it, don't use it. Shunning Smarty in general is just showing your ignorance for what it may offer for others.