# Limit the number of loops through array

Tags: php, smarty

How can I limit the amount of loops through an array using Smarty? Let's say that there's 32 items in a given array, I'd like to limit the number of loops to 8.

```
{foreach from=$friend_list key=userId item=userInfo name=friend_list}
    {if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index % 8 && $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index > 0 }
        </tr><tr>
    {/if}
        <td height='50' width='50'>
            <img border='0' height='50' src='http://graph.facebook.com/{$userInfo.user_uid}/picture' style='display:block;' width='50' />
        </td>
{/foreach}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{foreach from=$friend_list key=userId item=userInfo name=friend_list}
  {if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index < 8 }
    {if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index % 8 && $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index > 0 }
        </tr><tr>
    {/if}
        <td height='50' width='50'>
            <img border='0' height='50' src='http://graph.facebook.com/{$userInfo.user_uid}/picture' style='display:block;' width='50' />
        </td>
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

Read this [Smarty - foreach loop 10 times and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3474927/1164491)

ps: I intentionally left the `if` block with `if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.index % 8` in case if will need more than 8 loops. Otherwise that block could be removed (keeping `</tr><tr>` intact)

Answer (score 0):

add a counter before you open you foreach,

```
$i=1;
```

increase the counter on each loop (ie inside the foreach)

```
if($i = 8) break; 
$i++;
```

(where 8 is your limit)

you code looks all wrong so I didnt bother placing it in. Sort out the () {} issues

Comment: oh wait up, this is inside the smarty template right? why place so much logic in the presentation layer? wouldn't this be better in the PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Here, that should process the first 8 entries and ignore the rest. Unfortunately, there's no way to break from a Smarty for each.

```
{foreach from=$friend_list key=userId item=userInfo name=friend_list}
    {if $smarty.foreach.friend_list.iteration < 8}
        <td height='50' width='50'>
            <img border='0' height='50' src='http://graph.facebook.com/{$userInfo.user_uid}/picture' style='display:block;' width='50' />
        </td>
    {/if}
{/foreach}
```